# run an update on a linked MS Access table using php

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access

I have Microsoft Access Database (mdb file) with a table in it (we'll call that table A) that is linked to another Microsoft Access Database (we'll call that table B). I need to be able to update table A using php (which will in turn update table B, since A is linked to B). Please note that the table I'm linking to has a primary key named "Intersection" and it is set to Indexed: Yes (No duplicates).

If I use a simple `odbc_connect` and `odbc_exec` to run the following query:

```
$con= odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password)
$res = odbc_exec($con, "UPDATE tableA SET myfield=NULL WHERE myfield=2439;");
```

However, when I try this on a database with a linked table, I get the following error:

> Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query., SQL
>   state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in G:\web\libs\test.php on line 413

For some reason it seems that my database is not updateable even though it should be. It has a primary key defined and is a simple table (except for the fact that it's linked). Originally I was getting the following error:

> Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] 'H:\test\Database\test.mdb' is not a valid
>   path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you
>   are connected to the server on which the file resides., SQL state
>   S1009 in SQLExecDirect in G:\web\libs\test.php on line 413

But then I changed my linked table so instead of using drive letters to navigate to the linked table, I used the absolute \server\ path, which seemed to fix that problem, however not it is not able to be updated.

In case it helps, to create the Linked table, all I did was (Using MS Access 2010) I hit the "External Data" tab, then the "Access" (button), then I made sure to hit "Link to the source by creating a linked table" (option) and I selected the other database which contains the original table.

**Is there some way to run an update on a linked access table using php?**

Again, if you have a MS Access linked table that is linked to another table, and these tables have a primary key that is properly indexed. You CANNOT update the table using the following above PHP code (even though it works completely fine on an table which is not linked).

Please note, I have tested this with a fresh accdb database file as well, and if it is a linked table, it seems it will become read-only if you try to update the table using odbc_exec, however it does return data just fine, I just can't insert or update records.

Thank you.

[UPDATE]

Our server is running Windows Server 2003 with apache, and php.  So I set up a Windows 7 machine with apache, and php, and it **IS** able to update a linked database without a problem, so I suspect my problem (since it's the only difference between the machines that could affect this), is that the Win2003 server is running odbc v3.5 whereas my win7 Machine is running odbc v6.1.  I'm still looking into this further and will update this post if I find a solution to getting it working on our Windows Server 2003 machine.

Comment: Looking around at some other sites, I found some information related to permissions. It might be worth looking at both databases. http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/19783-help-i-cannot-insert-into-queries-with-odbc-exec/

Comment: I agree with @JonSturdevant that this is likely an issue with permissions. Specifically, the account under which the web server is running probably does not have write permissions on the remote folder containing the database that holds the table to which you are linking. You could try running similar PHP code from the command line under your own account to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: FWIW, I have tried the exact same code but with a normal table (one that is not linked) and it works great.  I'm hoping the permissions will fix it.  I have had little luck with finding a solution to this problem.  Thank you so much to both of you, I will try both of your suggestions and report back the results for anybody else encountering the same problem as me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have bad news, I added IUSR_SERVER and gave it full control to the folder and it still threw the same error.  Also, just to be thorough, I gave "Everyone" full control as well, and it still keeps throwing the "SQL state S1000" error, can you guys think of anything else?  Or can anybody else please verify that you can in fact use odbc to update a linked microsoft access table?

Comment: Did you add permissions to the database itself as well?

Comment: re: "can anybody else please verify that you can in fact use odbc to update a linked microsoft access table?" - Yes. When I tested it on my development machine where both databases were local and PHP was running under my own account I could indeed update the linked table.

Comment: @GordThompson really? that's great! thank you for testing that. Were you using a Microsoft access MDB file that was linked to another MDB file and you were able to modify the data in the linked table? (I just need to make sure you tested it right with the same setup)

Comment: @JonSturdevant I'm sorry Jon, I don't understand what you mean. This is a simple Microsoft Access Database, there are no permissions AFAIK, other than the file permissions. Please elaborate, or let me know if I'm being dense, thank you.

Comment: @Jared Yes. x.mdb contained a linked table pointing to a real table in y.mdb. My query updated the linked table in x.mdb and the change was successfully written to the actual table in y.mdb.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks again for the info.  If you don't mind me asking, what version of windows were you running on your development machine that you tested this "updating linked databases via php" on?  I have now converted my workstation (Windows 7) to act as a development machine, installed apache, and php, and when I tested it, it worked!  However, I need to get it working on our server, which is Windows Server 2003.  So I'm curious which version you tested with.  I suspect my problem with my server is the version of ODBC it's running is MUCH older than on my Win7 machine.  Thanks again!

Comment: Have you thought about using another driver? If you are happy with security and you can modify records directly, then I would suggest the driver.